# Change the picture onhover position along with the text

Tags: css, mouseover

[image]

I listed categories in my website on my home page. I want the image to change to the blue version of it onhover position. I also want that picture to change to the blue version when Computer Services heading is onhover in onhover position. I coded one way but it looks like is not working properly because I went inside of the image it changed then it went back several times. Is there anybody can help me with this ?

Here is the coding I made for this;
http://jsfiddle.net/4M2sr/

Note: I don`t want that black text to change the color of heading or picture.

Comment: keep in mind that your markup is not valid. You can't add a block-level element like `h3` in inline element such `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that your `<p>` tag is sitting on top of the other elements, blocking the on-hover effect when you mouse over the middle of the image.  There are a couple of ways you can fix this:

- Use `z-index` to fix this problem by forcing the `<p>` tag behind the other elements.
- Change the `<p>` tag to an inline tag, like `<span>`.
- Apply `display: inline` to the `<p>` tag's style.

Note: if you use the second or third, you may need to adjust the positioning styles of the `<p>` tag.